# Add extra fields openERP 7

Tags: customization, odoo

I need to add several extra fields to an existing openERP module, i red somewhere else that i need to do it through the menus

> First create the fields using Configuration -> Customization ->
>   Database Structure -> Fields

but i cant find that options or do i need to install something else so i have that functionality?

I also checked under the admin the techincal features, but nothing.

i have seen several post and other users directly add code 
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using opernerp 7?

Then you can add fields menu:

```
Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Fields
```

You have to give rights to user, so add group `Technical Features` to user.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the field in the DB structure.
   Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Fields
2. Add the field in the view
   Settings -> Technical -> User Interface -> Views

Answer (score 0):

In 7.0 you can find fields,

```
go to

Settings -> Technical ->  Database Structure -> Fields.
```

Thanx